# Yii2: how to send data from my form to my backend with an API in diferent servers?

Tags: ajax, api, url, yii2

I made my first API using the Yii2 [official tutorial](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/es/rest-quick-start). It works great with Postman (with GET and POST methods) but what I need is that my frontend send data to my backend (in JSON format) and both are in different servers

I made something similar with AJAX and jQuery for another project to update a employees list without the need of reloading all the page. Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/employees/employees?employeeId=123",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 4));
    },
    error: function(err) {              
        console.log("Employees error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
    }
});
```

So I have a form in my view that sends data to my controller and then it store them in my database.

But I am confused: should I use AJAX? How can I use my API with a URL in my backend and another URL in my frontend without using AJAX?

Comment: Do you mean that you have 2 different Yii applications, frontend and backend, on different servers? Do both of them have access to the same database? Or are you trying to _forward_ the data from one of them to the other?

Comment: I am trying to forward the data. :)